# concurrent use of a shared excel file

Tags: windows, excel, networking

"User1" sits in front of a client PC of a small LAN and process an .xlsx file, which is located in a shared network folder . "User2" tries to access the same file (or a shortcut of it) and gets "this is a file in read only mode", and can't modify it's content.

Is there a setting allowing concurrent use/modification to happen? For example by using instances of the file or something...
Thanks in advance!

p.s. Both users have xp and excel 2003 installed. The DNS server which hosts the file has a win server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Excel has a built in "Share Workbook" feature that may help you with that problem.

This link here http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/shared.php provides a good description of how to use it.

Comment: thanks! I'll try this out, reasonably it will solve this issue.